# rails: Is there a way to make nested resources work automatically with `link_to`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails app with nested resources, such as this:

```
resources :product do
  resources :sales
end
```

Where `Sale belongs_to Product`, and a `Sale` instance can not exist without a product.

I can use `link_to` + `@product` to directly link to a product:

```
<%= link_to @product.name, @product %>
```

That produces

```
<a href="/products/3">Strawberry Jam</a>
```

If I want to do something similar for a sale, however, I can not use a `@sale` alone. I must involve the product. This won't work:

```
<%= link_to @sale.date, @sale %>
```

I must use something like this:

```
<%= link_to @sale.date, [@sale.product, @sale] %>
```

The first case won't work because `sale_path` is not defined (only `product_sale_path` is).

My question is: Can I add something to the Sale model so that `link_to` (or `url_for`) automatically adds the "parent" (the product, in this case) when generating the url?

I have tried looking at [the implementation of `url_for`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb#L191) and I think I could do that by monkeypatching `HelperMethodBuilder.url.handle_model_call`, but I would rather not do that if there is another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would using shallow routes avoid your problem by exposing direct urls to the nested resource?

```
resources :products do
  resources :sales, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end
resources :sales, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Now `link_to @sale` will work, you only need to involve the product for `index, new, create`.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources (scroll down to shallow nesting)

Comment: I am going to take this one as the answer, although it is not what I ended up using (I gave all my models a `Linkable` module with a "path" method which returns `self`, and overrode that method when I needed to. I still had to do `link_to @sales.path` instead of just `@sales` though).

Answer (score 2):

Using shallow nesting might help:

```
resources :product do
  resources :sales, shallow: true
end
```

Have a look at section 2.7.2 of the 
[Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) guide.

Comment: strange how two answers recommending the same solution given at the same moment in time, one gets upvotes and other does not. +1 for justice :)

Comment: @Matt 's answer is more detailed, and he posted it a few seconds before - he deserves more credit.

Comment: well, when I opened the question I saw two `answered 12 mins ago` :)

Answer (score 1):

`link_to @sale.date product_sale_path(@sale.product, @sale)`

Or

`link_to @sale.date product_sale_path(@sale.product_id, @sale)`

Will link to the `/products/:product_id/sales/:id` path.

I am guessing a product can have more than one sale. To link to the index action you only need the product.

`link_to product_sales_path(@sale.product)`